# getElementsByTagName returns length 0

Tags: javascript, php

For the page : http://watchimport.eu/product_info.php?products_id=13497

I was using `getElementsByTagName` for body tag but the length return 0 for this.

Actually, I wanted to check for `Product not found!`

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Example code please

Comment: Are you trying to do: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')`?

Comment: Well I think you have some error with your code. Because there is no problem with getElementsByTagName('body') : http://i.imgur.com/c1tgkUg.jpg

Comment: @WillReese $doc = new DOMDocument();
     @$doc->loadHTMLFile($fldProductLink);
$doc->getElementsByTagName('body')

Answer (score 0):

You can check content of this page by following code:

```
document.querySelector("table.infoBox:nth-child(1)").innerText
```

Comment: Is ther php version for this as am using : $doc = new DOMDocument();
     @$doc->loadHTMLFile($link);

Comment: Ok you didn't give it earlier. I suggest you use javascript, it will be easier and is best practice.